# Is There a KVM Switch That...?

Tags: networking, ethernet, switch

Reposting From [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1122941/is-there-a-kvm-switch-that), as it was closed there (Off Topic).  Moving here as I'm still at a loss on how to troubleshoot the issue.  Please use the link above to read the comments if needed or wanted.

---

### Possible Solution

I have an Intel Mac, a PC, and a Pi4 plugged into a TripLite 4Port HDMI KVM Switch.  I'm curious if there is a switch like this with a built in Ethernet Port, so that I don't need 4 Ethernet Cables (one in each device).  I'd rather have one coming from a switch into the KVM and each device recognize the one port on the KVM and have 1 IP address shared in all 4 devices.  In short, I want all traffic to go through the KVM.

### Actual Issue

Based on the comment I gave below, and the possibility of more negative slide, here is my actual problem, with my current Home LAN Setup first:

```
Setup
ISP Modem => 16 port unmanaged Netgear in Attic => 
Double Ethernet Outlet [Top: Desktop && Bottom: 4 Port Unmanaged 
Netgear => Devices Below]
```

For about 6 months, I could Turn on my Pi and SSH from the desktop.  I was doing this one afternoon and the Ethernet on my Desktop just quit. The status Icon in Windows 11 disappeared.  Rebooting into both Windows and Gentoo Linux for troubleshooting did not solve the issue.  In both OS's the card existed but was inactive.  The only way I can get the systems to use the card again is to disconnect the cable from the desktop and plug it into the Mac.  Once the status light goes yellow on the Mac I can disconnect the cable and plug it into the desktop again.

**Note**: I can no longer plug in the Pi or the Mac Ethernet cables into their ports without killing the desktop connection. The ideal solution would be to have everything plugged into the network and working.

**Note 2**: I used the snap type wall jacks without the punch down blocks.  Could these be causing the problem?

Comment: I have never seen a KVM with ethernet.  Granted, why would you?  Ethernet goes to network switches, not KVMs.

Comment: If the KVM can share devices, why not share an Ethernet Port??  That was my thought.  I'd rather fix the issue though.

Comment: The KVM doesn't *share* devices, it *switches* the devices to one of the systems at a time. That's certainly possible to implement with an Ethernet port, but what would be the point of doing so, if it limited only one system at a time to having network access – a limitation that your regular Ethernet packet-switch doesn't have? (After all, most headless systems exist with permanent network access in mind.) So while possible to do technically, likely everybody would avoid it in favor of an Ethernet switch anyway... or the KVM itself would be manufactured with an Ethernet packet switch built in.

Comment: @user1686 I agree with that, and as such that is how I built the setup described in the Actual Problem Heading.  What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Can't say but "switch port is fried" would be my main guess, as we had that happen at work on 3 different occasions this year already... Does the Ethernet card's driver log anything to Windows eventvwr.msc (the App or System logs) or to Gentoo dmesg?

Comment: Wait, I just reread this.  Someone out there actually uses Gentoo?!